# Pass multiple arrays of objects to a function

Tags: c++

The error that im getting is randm.cpp:42:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘Neuron::activationFunc(double&, double&)’ neu.activationFunc(feature[2][4], predicted[2][1]);

Is it possible to pass arrays or will i have to find another way of doing it? Here is my code. Its been a few years since i used classes so im a tad bit rusty.

`#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int correct = 0;

class Neuron {
    //double (&features)[150][4];

    public:
    double alpha = 0.5;
    double w1 = 1.0;
    double w2 = -1; 
    double w3 = 0.5;
    double w4 = 0;
    double x = 0;
    int theta = 1;
    int hardLim = 0;
    int track = 0;
    //void testClass();
    void activationFunc(double feature[2][4], double predicted[2][1]);

};
void Neuron::activationFunc (double feature[2][4], double predicted[2][1]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        x = (w1*feature[i][0]) + (w2*feature[i][1]) + (w3*feature[i][2]) + (w4*feature[i][3]) + predicted[2][1];
        cout <<"\n X value is: " << x << endl;
    //hardLimit(x);
    //track = i;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //feature = col 1-4, predicted = col 5
    double feature[2][4]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    double predicted[2][1]={4,5};
    Neuron neu;
    neu.activationFunc(feature[2][4], predicted[2][1]);

}`

Thanks. P.S. I know there are a few things in my code that arent used yet.

Comment: Put your arrays inside a struct, then pass the struct.  `struct Feature { double value[2][4]; };` and `struct Predicted { double value[2][1]; };`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Comment: Turn on more warnings. You are accessing elements outside your array-bounds. `predicted[2][1]`

Comment: `neu.activationFunc(feature[2][4], predicted[2][1]);` You are not passing a multi-dim array but you are only passing an element. to do so pass only the name of the array:  `neu.activationFunc(feature, predicted);`.
`

Answer (score 1):

To make it compile you need to change this line:

```
neu.activationFunc(feature[2][4], predicted[2][1]);
```

so that it looks like this instead:

```
neu.activationFunc(feature, predicted);
```

Comment: Note that you omit the “array sizes” here because they would be subscripts instead (to pick a single element, although these are of course out of range).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the multi-dimension array by reference or by pointer:

Your method prototype should look like:

```
class Neuron {
    //...
    void activationFunc(double(&)[2][4], double(&)[2][1]);
};
```

And the definition:

```
void Neuron::activationFunc (double (&feature)[2][4], double (&predicted)[2][1]) {
    for (size_t i{}; i != 2; ++i) {
        x = (w1 * feature[i][0]) + (w2 * feature[i][1]) + 
            (w3 * feature[i][2]) + (w4 * feature[i][3]) + predicted[1][0];
        std::cout << "X value is: " << x << std::endl;
    }

}
```

And in main just pass the arrays names:

```
neu.activationFunc(feature, predicted);
```

- There is an Undefined Behavior in your loop:

  ```
  x = (w1*feature[i][0]) + (w2*feature[i][1]) + (w3*feature[i][2]) + (w4*feature[i][3]) + predicted[2][1];
  ```

`predicted` is an array of `[2][1]` dimension so the valid range is `[1][0]` not `[2][1]`.